# html-docx-js- watermark not inserted in generated docx in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, docx

I am successfully created docx file from html using html-docx-js,but unable to get watermark symbol in docx pages.

```
<div id="html-to-pdf" class="bgdraftWaterMark'">
    <table>....</table>
    <table>....</table>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

below code has been written for generating docx:

```
 var content=document.getElementById('html-to-pdf')
  style = `
  <style>
     .bgdraftWaterMark {
     background-image: url(../../assets/images/draft.png);
     background-repeat: repeat-y;
     /*background-position: center;*/
     }
 </style>
  `
     var converted = htmlDocx.asBlob(content);
     converted=style + converted;
     saveAs(converted, 'test.docx');
```

can any one help what exactly code snippet required to get water mark and place at center in all docx pages.